# Not able to get the userprofile info of google+

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-plus

I am able to retrieve the access token of google account.But I am unable to get the userprofile info.I am getting null pointer exception.Why i cant understand.
Below I have provided two methods using which we get access token and also gets the userprofile info.

It would be great if you help me.

MainActivity.java

```
private void tryAuthenticate() {
    if (isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    mToken = null;
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                mToken =
                        GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, mChosenAccountName, "oauth2:"
                                + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" + " "+" https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read"+" " +YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE + " "
                                + YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD);


            } catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException playEx) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(playEx.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                        MainActivity.this, REQUEST_GMS_ERROR_DIALOG).show();
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
                // Start the user recoverable action using the intent
                // returned by
                // getIntent()
                startActivityForResult(userAuthEx.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE);
                return false;
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // TODO: backoff
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), transientEx.getMessage());
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), authEx.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean hideProgressBar) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            if (hideProgressBar) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }

            if (mToken != null) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        saveAccount();
                    }
                });
            }
            loadData();
        }
    };
    task.execute((Void) null);
}

private void loadProfile() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Person>() {
        @Override
        protected Person doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();

            credential.setAccessToken(mToken);

            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();


            Plus plus =
                    new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
                            Constants.APP_NAME).build();

            try {


             return plus.people().get("me").execute();  //here am getting null pointer exception

            } catch (final GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                if (401 == e.getDetails().getCode()) {
                    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
                    GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(MainActivity.this, mToken);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tryAuthenticate();
                        }
                    }, mCurrentBackoff * 1000);

                    mCurrentBackoff *= 2;
                    if (mCurrentBackoff == 0) {
                        mCurrentBackoff = 1;
                    }
                }

            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Person me) {

           mUploadsListFragment.setProfileInfo(me);
        }

    }.execute((Void) null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you have mixed and matched a lot of things all together. The line at which you are getting a Null Pointer is because the `me` is not defined anywhere else in the program and hence when the get method is called it is not able to find the value.

Secondly, you can separate out the code in two different files if you want to perform a set of two different operations. If you just want to retrieve the information regarding the profile information of a Google+ User account please follow the [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/).

Comment: I saw somewhere in the example "me" means the authenticated user. why it is not recognizing the user who was authenticated?